# How to display list of content items using Telerik Grid component

Tags: telerik, orchardcms

I'm begginer in the Orchard CMS.
I would like to create Content Type composed from different parts and fields which I know before. I want this content type to be enumerable ie I use content part List, I want to list it using telerik components.

For example my content type is Product and I specify its fields: Price, SKU apart from default: user(who created it) and creation time fields. Moreover the product contains also image gallery, ie image gallery content part.. I want the list of products to be shown using Telerik component Grid, including creation time and user name.

Is it better to create the whole module specifying all its fields(price,SKU) and its templates or is there any way to just take what has been already created in orchard as a content type and display it different way(using telerik)..

thanks for any advice ;)
Tomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears this topic was moved and answered here:

http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/371276